# Optimizing a distinct on a parent table in a multi-level join in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.7, distinct

I have the following tables: in a MySQL 5 database:

- `projects` - 1,000 rows
- `tasks` (FKed to `projects`) - 10,000 rows
- `task_tags` (FKed to `tasks`) - 350,000 rows
- `task_comments` (FKed to `tasks`) - 750,000 rows

and want to get a list of projects for which any task has exactly  the word *urgent* in a tag or comment, i.e.

```sql
select DISTINCT p.*
from projects p
join tasks t on p.id = t.project_id
left join task_tags tt on t.id = tt.task_id
left join task_comments tc on t.id = tc.task_id
where tt.value = 'urgent' OR tc.text = 'urgent'
```

Without the `DISTINCT`, the query executes in well under 0.1 second (and the indices used look sensible). The Visual Execution Plan is (with the tables being `projects`, `tasks`, `task_tags` and `task_comments` in that order from left to right):

[image: MySQL plan for query without DISTINCT]

Adding the `DISTINCT` makes the query seriously unperformant (on the order of minutes), with the DISTINCT being added on after the last nested loop, and thus I believe requiring MySQL to sort all the resulting rows, and then deduplicate them.

While this is correct, it does not feel like the best possible option--after all, once we know that a project meets the criteria, there is no point checking any other tasks for that project as this isn't e.g. `select distinct p.*, t.id` - but I don't know how to encourage MySQL to plan this more sensibly because I don't know what plan I want.

I have tried something along the lines of

```sql
select distinct project_id
from tasks
where id in (
    select task_id from task_tags where value = 'urgent'
    union
    select task_id from task_comments where text = 'urgent'
)
```

as an alternative but we are also on the order of minutes for that though I believe it is slightly faster, and I have no other great ideas (except for things not in MySQL 5 like persisted views, but upgrading the DB is not a practical option at this stage).

Any ideas as to what I could try (or even where to investigate next)? The database model is fairly fixed, but certainly I can add indices and happy to look at options.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. It would help if we had the respective DDL of the tables involved, just to on the safe side, and possibly any indexes that may have already been created. Have you tried [`OPTIMIZE TABLE...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html)? Otherwise a very decent first question. Good luck.

Comment: What about the second query, but with `union all` or as an `or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's turn it inside-out so we can see that it is starting at the right places.  The Optimizer won't do this work for us.

1. Start with each table that might say 'urgent'
2. `UNION` them.  (`UNION DISTINCT` is slightly slower than `UNION ALL`, but you might get two duplicate rows.  You decide.)
3. Join to `tasks` to get the `project_id`
4. Finally, reach into `projects` for the few rows that are needed.  (Note how both of your formulations effectively require fetching all of `p` before figuring out that most of the rows aren't needed.)

Switching from `OR` to `UNION` was a good idea, but `IN ( SELECT ... )` is not an efficient construct.

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM (
         SELECT t.project_id
            FROM task_comments tc
            JOIN tasks t  ON t.id = tc.task_id
            WHERE tc.text = 'urgent'  -- see Note
         ) UNION DISTINCT (
         SELECT t.project_id
            FROM task_tags tt
            JOIN tasks t  ON t.id = tt.task_id
            WHERE tt.value = 'urgent'
         ) AS x
    JOIN projects p  ON p.id = x.project_id
```

That will need

```
tc:  INDEX(text, task_id)  -- see Note
t:   (I assume you have PRIMARY KEY(id))
tt:  INDEX(value, task_id)
p:   (I assume you have PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Note:  Perhaps you really want to check for "urgent" anywhere in `tc.text`?  If so, the best way to optimize it is to have

```
tc:  FULLTEXT(text)
```

and switch to

```
WHERE MATCH(tc.text) AGAINST ('+urgent' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thanks! That takes it down to about ~2 seconds; not exactly ideal but it's not used that frequently so I guess it'll do. (And in the real case, it is meant to be an equality check, not a fulltext search; I just couldn't come up with a good example so went with that as the example)

Comment: @waiwai933 - It might be useful to show the (non-Visual) `EXPLAIN` for my version with my indexes.  (2 seconds seems high; I'll check for a mistake somewhere.)  Oh, I assume you don't have thousands of "urgent" projects; if you do, that might be an explanation for "2 seconds".

Comment: Full explain (both tabular and visual source) at: https://gist.github.com/waiwaing/f3bd487d7ca500df04d625ec4ac694f6, and about 2k urgent projects, as it were. 

(FWIW, this is used only in an admin-only interface and we can cache the result, so while tuning it a bit more would definitely be nice, the suggestion you gave of converting the IN to a JOIN is probably sufficient for the use case anyway)

Comment: Are there thousands of rows with 'urgent'?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; something looks inconsistent.